# I need to have the data from a list in another site at the same level to be available as a lookup in sharepoint 2010

Tags: lookup-column, cross-site

I have a parent team site (Services) that contains multiple sub sites.
One of the sub Teamsites is Call Inventory Containing our Stock List.
Another Teamsite is called Purchasing containing a purchase request list.

I need the ability to have a lookup on the Purchase Request list to be the Stock List.

I just can't find a way to do it? I've looked on here and from what I can get is the Stock list needs to be at the Services Level site and can't be at the subsite level.

I'm stuck and realy need help on this..

Comment: not sure but maybe site column is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Option to achieve it would be:

1. Take advantage of a product doing it (Bamboo solutions, etc.)
2. Use this trick here http://bramnuyts.be/2011/04/11/creating-a-cross-site-lookup-field-without-code/
3. Build a BDC Model via BCS and then you could create a new column, and not just for a sub-site or site collection, but for the whole farm.
4. Not exactly a lookup but also you could opt for Managed Metadata with a Site Collection scoped term-set which you could reuse anywhere as a Column